# How to optimize loading from Firestore to Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, database, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

My View Controller has a Tableview with 2 segments. Depending on which Segment is selected, the Tableview displays a different set of data.

```
@IBAction func didChangeSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            model.getRecipes(starredTrue: false)
        }
        else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            model.getRecipes(userAdded: true)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipe.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealPlanCell", for: indexPath) as! MealPlanCell
        
        let recipeInTable = recipe[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.displayRecipe(recipe: recipeInTable, indexPathRow: indexPath.row)
        
        return cell
    }
```

And this is how `model.getRecipes()` gets data from Firestore before returning it to the Tableview:

```
        let recipeQuery = db.collection("recipes")
        
        let docRef = recipeQuery.document(documentId)
        
        docRef.getDocument { document, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                self.errorMessage = "Error getting document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            }
            else {
                if let document = document {
                    do {
                        self.recipe = try document.data(as: Recipe.self)
                        
                        let recipeFromFirestore = Recipe(
                            id: documentId,
                            title: self.recipe!.title ?? "")
                        
                        self.recipes.append(recipeFromFirestore)
                    }
                    catch {
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegateRecipes?.recipesRetrieved(recipes: self.recipes)
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue I'm having is that the Tableview takes a very long time to display data. It appears this is because it has to wait for the model to finish loading all the data from Firestore every time I select one of the segments.

How can I optimize this process? Is it possible to have the TableView load/display cell by cell, instead of needing to wait for *all* data to be loaded?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to get all data everytime segment changes ??...You can add snapShotListener and get document changes and reload only changed data's row ...which just takes fraction of time in compare to getAllDocuments...

Comment: @NayanDave The segments are pulling data from 2 different Firestore collections. There are a lot of differences between the segments.

Comment: @ amirbt17 You can still add different listeners for both firestore..it's upto you which changes you want to show according to the selected segment.